# spark `like operation optimize

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

let's assume I have the following spark df's:

```
df_with_wild_card = spark.createDataFrame(
   [("random_key", "%")],
   ["key", "value"]
)

df_with_long_value_column = spark.createDataFrame(
   [("value1"),
   ("value2"),
   ("value3"),
   ("value4") ... ],
   ["value"]
)
```

and I want to join those two df's like this :

```
df_with_long_value_column .alias("df_with_long_value_column").join(
            f.broadcast(df_with_wild_card.alias("df_with_wild_card")),
            f.expr("df_with_long_value_column.value like df_with_wild_card.value"),
            "inner",
        )
```

obviously, because df_with_wild_card.value is just one value which is "%", every value from df_with_long_value_column.value should be on the result df from the join operation.

my question: is spark actually check for every value in df_with_long_value_column.value if it's catch by "%" or spark recognize that the only value is "%" and it takes all the values automatically to the result df.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at execution plan

[image]

So it looks like your join is treated like other joins. Its broadcasted because dataset is smaller than 10mb and its nestedLoops because its non-equi join.

So yes, Your elements from first dataset are going to be check one by one against values from second dataset

I can imagine that this may be optimized somehow in Catalyst during logical plan optimization but i can't find such optimizer rule

Here you can see default rules batch: [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L79)

In this batch you can find one rule which is connected to like operator: [LikeSimplification](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/expressions.scala#L707) you can review its code but i think that its not connected with your case